How to make IntelliJ open a project inside a dot-directory on a Mac?
Running IntelliJ on a Mac, I need to open a '.teamcity' directory as a project - it contains a Kotlin DSL.
Unfortunately, when I try to 'open' that folder in IntelliJ, the file dialogue only offers me normal-looking folders.
I tried pressing 'option' and other modifier keys, in case they revealed the hidden directories (in the same way that 'option' changes the dock menu 'Quit' to 'Force quit') but no joy. Nothing in settings stood out either.

Turns out you can press / when the dialogue has focus and then type the fully-rooted pathname into the field that pops up.
